# MS access editing an attachment object in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to take an attached excel file from a DAO.recordset, open it, edit it with new information and resave the file to the database all within MS Access 2007. Currently I am having trouble finding any similar task that someone has completed so that I can see how to open an attachment object from a DAO.recordset within vba. I'm guessing it isn't too bad to do once I get past the opening a saved attachment part. I have yet to find any reference material on this topic. Has anyone done anything like this or know how to edit an attachment within vba?

Any insight would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attached Excel worksheet or Named Range is *read-only* from Access since version 2000.

You should browse for automation - on how to open Excel from Access and then manipulate the worksheet. Plenty of examples out there.

Comment: Thanks, I will move forward on that lead!